# Autoform Hooks onSuccess

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, hook, meteor-autoform

I'm having an issue getting the autoform hook to work. Currently I am using this quickform.

```
{{>quickForm id="studentForm" collection="Students" type="insert" template="bootstrap3-horizontal" label-class="col-sm-3" input-col-class="col-sm-9"}}
```

I want a success message to appear when a form is successfully submitted. Currently I have an event working with this code:

```
Template.home.events({
    "submit #student-form": function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        swal("Success!", "You have been added to the WaitList", "success")
    }
});
```

I am attempting to use the autoform hook like so:

```
AutoForm.hooks({
    studentForm: {
        onSuccess: function(insert, result) {
            swal("Success!", "You have been added to the wait list", "success")
        }
    }
})
```

This is not working for me at the moment and I am stumped on why this is not working. Documentation for autoform hooks [here](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#callbackshooks).

Any ideas on what my issue is here?

Comment: just a wild guess, but did you try commenting out the preventDefault()?

Comment: Yep that did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Great I'll make it an answer

Answer (score 0):

It's apparently being blocked by the event's preventDefault().